# Get the the top-level parent of a custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical, terms

How would I get the top-level parent of a given term?

I am using `wp_get_object_terms` to get taxonomy terms on posts, but instead of showing all tagged terms, I only want to show tagged terms' top-level parents.

So if these are my selected terms, I only want to show Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner.

```
x BREAKFAST
   x Cereal
   x Eggs
  LUNCH
     Hamburger
   x Pizza
  DINNER
     Fish
        Bass
      x Salmon
        Trout
     Lasagna
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to Ivaylo for this code, which was based on Bainternet's answer.

The first function below, `get_term_top_most_parent`, accepts a term and taxonomy and returns the the term's top-level parent (or the term itself, if it's parentless); the second function (`get_top_parents`) works in the loop, and, given a taxonomy, returns an HTML list of the top-level parents of a post's terms.

```php
// Determine the top-most parent of a term
function get_term_top_most_parent( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    // Start from the current term
    $parent  = get_term( $term, $taxonomy );
    // Climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
    while ( $parent->parent != '0' ) {
        $term_id = $parent->parent;
        $parent  = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $parent;
}
```

Once you have the function above, you can loop over the results returned by `wp_get_object_terms` and display each term's top parent:

```php
function get_top_parents( $taxonomy ) {
    // get terms for current post
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
    $top_parent_terms = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        //get top level parent
        $top_parent = get_term_top_most_parent( $term, $taxonomy );
        //check if you have it in your array to only add it once
        if ( !in_array( $top_parent, $top_parent_terms ) ) {
            $top_parent_terms[] = $top_parent;
        }
    }

    // build output (the HTML is up to you)
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $top_parent_terms as $term ) {
          //Add every term
          $output .= '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see a modification that wouldn't just print out the top-level terms but, rather, all terms beneath the top-most parent, hierarchically.

Comment: @RobertAndrews If you just need the children of a single term, you can use WordPress's built-in `get_term_children( $term, $taxonomy )` ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)). 

If you wanted to to get all children of a given term's top-level parent, you could pass the above result into it, like this: `get_term_children( get_term_top_most_parent( $term, $taxonomy ), $taxonomy )`.

Comment: What is $term in this case, ie. the object, the name of the term, the prefixed taxonomyname_number? In all cases, this method is extremely long to load. I've been waiting for the page to load for several minutes now.

Comment: As originally written it expected an ID, but I edited the answer to allow a term ID or WP_Term object. 

You're [not the only one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63277/how-to-get-the-top-most-term-top-ancestor-of-a-custom-taxonomy-child-term?rq=1) reporting an issue with this code—ideally it should be rewritten to use WP's built-in `get_ancestors` function, which was new and not well documented when the answer was written. I will post a new answer when I've had time to test.

Answer (score 24):

Since 3.1.0, [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) is available. It returns an array of ancestors from lowest to highest in the hierarchy.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple function that will get you the top most parent term of any given term:

```
function get_term_top_most_parent( $term_id, $taxonomy ) {
    $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy );
    while ( $parent->parent != 0 ){
        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $parent->parent, $taxonomy );
    }
    return $parent;
}
```

Once you have this function you can just loop over the results returned by `wp_get_object_terms`:

```
$terms =  wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );
$top_parent_terms = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    //Get top level parent
    $top_parent = get_term_top_most_parent( $term->ID, 'taxomony' );

    //Check if you have it in your array to only add it once
    if ( !in_array( $top_parent->ID, $top_parent_terms ) ) {
        $top_parent_terms[] = $top_parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this now. FYI I think you're missing a close paren in line 1 of the function.

Comment: do I need to add $taxonomy as a second parameter in $top_parent?

Comment: I added the $taxonomy parameter but am getting an error when I use this code, here: https://gist.github.com/1122631

Comment: yeah you do. i updated the answer.

Comment: With that fixed, do you know why the code here (http://gist.github.com/1122631) wouldn't be working?

Comment: your function seems broken your foreach loops are overlapping try this: http://pastebin.com/u48dxzap
and if you still get an error paste all of you code and i'll check

Comment: It still gives the same error; if I print_r($top_parent_terms), I get an empty array, so maybe the problem is actually with the first function? My version here - http://pastebin.com/cMUxs9Nn

Comment: OK think the problem is with `get_the_ID` which works in the loop so try this: http://pastebin.com/u48dxzap

Comment: @Bainternet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/985/discussion-between-supertrue-and-bainternet)

Comment: @Bainternet-it automatically posted that chat message? Re global $post and post->ID, I am using this within WP_Query loops so get_the_ID should be working.

Comment: No you are using it in a function called by the loop, does it work?

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Get top level term
 */
function get_top_level_term($term,$taxonomy){
    if($term->parent==0) return $term;
    $parent = get_term( $term->parent,$taxonomy);
    return get_top_level_term( $parent , $taxonomy );
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation along with your code.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved easily. Check this out:

Define `$taxonomy`. It can be the slug of the taxonomy you want to get the data.
After doing this, you can simply do this:

```
<?php
    $postterms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);   // get post terms
    $parentId = $postterms[0]->parent;                      // get parent term ID
    $parentObj = get_term_by('id', $parentId, $taxonomy);   // get parent object 
?>
```

Now you got something like this:

```
object(stdClass)#98 (11) {
  ["term_id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Esportes"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(8) "esportes"
  ["term_group"]=>
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(17) "noticiaseditorias"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["object_id"]=>
  int(123)
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}
```

And you can use `$parentObj` to get slug, name, id, whatever. Just by using `$parentObj->slug` or `$parentObj->name` as exemple.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way:

```
$rootId = end( get_ancestors( $term_id, 'my_taxonomy' ) );
$root = get_term( $rootId, 'my_taxonomy' );
echo $root->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:  `get_ancestors( $object_id, $object_type );`

[codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
function get_term_top_most_parent( $term_id, $taxonomy ) {
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, $taxonomy );

    if(!empty($ancestors)){
        $parentID = end( $ancestors );
    }else{
        $parentID = $term_id;
    }
    return $parentID;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?