# How can I get parent term from a child term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template, terms

I have a custom post type and a taxonomy, when adding a post if I select a child term and not the parent term then I cannot use get terms as the parent term wont be in the array as it wasn't selected so I was wondering if it possible to get the parent term/id using a child term?

As I was to do an if statement so that if a single post parent term is (id 4) then display something.

So I need to get terms (all of which will be a child term and using the child term get the parent term for that term)

Comment: This question with answers can probably help you get going... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term

Comment: Thanks for the link however that example means the user has selected the top level parent they wish to display where as I want to display the top level parent based on if the child term which is selected.

Comment: You're right, it's not the exact solution you are looking for as it goes all the way to the top level parent. That's why I said it could get you going... in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the loop you can make use of [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to return all the terms associated with the specific post. This object returned holds all the terms with all the properties of the specified terms

With that in mind, you can use a `foreach` loop to get each term, and then check each term's parent. For grandchild terms you will need to do some extra checking here to determine the parent or top most level term parent

You can do something like this

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->parent == 4 ) {
            //Do something if parent is 4
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

To make this work with deeper level categories, you can use [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get all levels and use `in_array()` to test for the specific category ID

You can extend the function as follow:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if( $term->parent != 4 && $term->parent == 0 )
            continue;

        if ( $term->parent == 4 || in_array( 4, get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'category' ) )) {
            //Do something if parent ID is 4
        } else {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to find out how i can extend it so that if the category is more than 1 depth

Comment: See my update, should work in theory :-)