# Taxonomy , subtaxonomy,child taxonomy of a product woocommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

Hi  i need to get the main taxonomy and sub taxonomy of a product in woocommerce . i know how to get taxonomy  details  .`123 is product id .`

```
$terms = get_the_terms(123, 'product_cat');
```

I know how to get taxonomy  name also

```
 echo $terms[0]->name
```

But my need is:
 Nokia 3110 is my mobile . So it is under `electronics-> mobiles -->ordinary-->Single sim-->nokia 3110`

```
id is 123 .
```

in product edit page on admin-panel  nokia 3110 is under single sim [actually single sim is under **electronics-> mobiles -->ordinary**].But I Only checked the single sim check box, not checked electronics, mobiles, ordinary etc  .

My need is from this id i need to get mainly in which taxonmy nokia 31110 is . The answer is It is in Electronics. And i need the second taxonomy also , that is i need to print  it is under mobiles . How to get these details

Thank you .

i know how to get topmost taxonomy

```
function get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy){
    // start from the current term
    $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    // climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
    while ($parent->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $parent->parent;

        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $parent;
}
```

but please help to find second top taxonomy .

Comment: You'll find useful informations [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term) =)

Comment: But how can i find second parent . This function very help to find topmost parent .But how to find second most. Please look this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term), here is my function to get all your terms in an array :

```
function get_term_ancestors($post_id, $taxonomy){
    // Declare the array where we are going to store the terms
    $ancestors = array();
    // start from the current term
    $parent  = array_shift(get_the_terms($post_id,$taxonomy));
    // climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
    while ($parent->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $parent->parent;

        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
        $ancestors[] = $parent;
    }
    return $ancestors;
}
```

Use as follow :

```
$ancestors = get_term_ancestors(123,'product_cat');
```

So with this function, your top level term will be :

```
$ancestors[count($ancestors)-1] // or array_pop($ancestors);
```

and your second top level parent will be

```
$ancestors[count($ancestors)-2] // or another array_pop($ancestors)
```

Please also note than you should check isset($ancestors[count($ancestors)-2]) before trying to access it

**Warning :** This will only work for products which are in one term. This function does not handle multiple terms