# How to get post's current parent term ID?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

How do you get the ID of the parent term of the current child term assigned to a post. For a custom taxonomy?

Custom taxonomy: "location"

Countries

- Japan
- USA
- Mexico

Cities

- New York
- Austin

Say we are on a post assigned to "Japan" how do I get the ID of the parent called "Countries"? For this case it doesn't matter if it takes the highest parent or just the direct parent.

I found this:

```
$term_id = 21;

$child_term = get_term( $term_id, 'location' );
$parent_term = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'location' );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need IDs, [`get_ancestors`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) will return an array of parents for any type of object:

```
$term_id = 21;
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'location' );
```

Comment: Will it return more than one parent if the structure is nested deeper? How do I just get the single ID of the parent directly above the child term?

Comment: Check the function name it says "ancestor**s**" which mean all parents. To get immediate parent use `$immediate_parent = array_shift($ancestors);`

Comment: thanks champ, figured they could work that out for themselves, but there you go!