# How to show all possible parents and children of a hierarchical taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, children

I have a hierarchical custom taxonomy "`company`".

Companies are hierarchical, they can have both owners and subsidiaries. So, some of my "`company`" terms have parents and children. Take this real example of a set of my "`company`" terms

- WPP

  - 24/7 realmedia
  - AKQA
  - GroupM

    - Finecast
    - Group M Entertainment
    - Maxus
    - MEC
    - MediaCom
    - Modi Media
    - Real Media Group
    - Xaxis
  - JWT
  - Kantar

    - Kantar Media
    - TNS Media Intelligene
  - Millward Brown
  - Ogilvy

    - Ogilvy Entertainment
  - Possible
  - VML
  - Wavemaker
  - Wunderman

What I'd like to do, on a `company` term page, is to show the full corporate tree, as above, in order to situate the term in its full hierarchical context.

That goes not just for the top-most term, eg. "WPP", but also a mid-hierarchy child or grand-child, eg. "GroupM" or "Ogilvy Entertainment.

I don't mean all terms in the "`company`" taxonomy, I mean all terms up and down from the given term, including children of upper terms.

In other words, for any term, spin back up to the top-most parent and display all sub terms properly, in an indented HTML list - preferably with something unique applied to the current term title, eg. no `get_term_link` applied.

What I have so far is the following...

```
  <?php
      // Parents
      $parent_args = array(
        'inclusive' => 'false'
      );
      echo get_term_parents_list( $organisation->term_id, 'company', $parent_args );
      ?>


      <?php
      // Children
      $org_children = get_term_children( $organisation->term_id, 'company' ); // Get child terms of this

      echo '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
      foreach ( $org_children as $org_child ) {
        $child_term = get_term_by( 'id', $org_child, 'company' );
        $child_id_prefixed = 'company_'. $child_term->term_id;
                if (empty(get_field( 'domain', $child_id_prefixed ))) {
                    $favicon = 'null';
                } else {
                    $favicon = get_field( 'domain', $child_id_prefixed );
                }

        echo '<li><small><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='. $favicon.'" width="12" class="mr-2"><a href="' . get_term_link( $org_child, 'company' ) . '">' . $child_term->name . '</a></small></li>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';
      ?>
```

Which produces this...

[image]

However, this:

1. Is a two-step process, in which I get parents and then children (I'd prefer a singular process).
2. The output is not an indented list.

So, how to show all possible parents and children of a hierarchical taxonomy term?

Comment: The answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25035/39300 seems to go some way, in that it gets the top-most parent term of a given term - but I'd then like to show a hierarchical, HTML list of all terms beneath it.

Comment: Any ideas, i wonder?